# create is deprecated: use new Observable() instead - usage with pipe and debounceTime

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have upgraded my angular app and tslint gives the following errors:

> create is deprecated: use new Observable() instead

The code that it is complaining of:

```
this.subs$ = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.edited.code);
    }).pipe(
        debounceTime(defaultInputDebounceTime),
        mergeMap((searchTerm: string) => this.getStrings(searchTerm))
    );
```

I've tried to use the `new Observable()` form but then it has a problem with debounceTime. What am I missing here?

```
this.subs$ = new Observable((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.edited.code);
    }).pipe(
        debounceTime(defaultInputDebounceTime), // <- gives error
        mergeMap((searchTerm: string) => this.getStrings(searchTerm))
    );
```

> Error TS2345  (TS) Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'OperatorFunction'.
>         Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>           Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.

rxjs 6.5.2

**Update**

After replacing `Observable.create()` with `of()` it still complaints about incompatible types:

> TS2345    (TS) Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'OperatorFunction'.   Type
>   'Observable' is not assignable to type
>   'Observable'.
>       Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

The types of my variables are:

```
this.edited.code: string | undefined;
subs$: Observable<ListData[]> | undefined;
```

Comment: They've updated the api, try use the of operator instead of new Observable. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of

Comment: `of` is not a replacement for `new Observable`, this is legit.

Comment: @maxime1992 it kinda is, if the only thing in the create is a `.next`, or am i missing something

Comment: In this case `of` is the way to go as he's trying to wrap a value into an observable and he doesn't need to keep the stream open nor make any kind of *clean up*. But what if you want to wrap a web socket into an observable for ex? Then you use `new Observable` because you can manage the values, the errors, and the teardown (when unsubscribing the the stream, stop the ws for ex). So no, `of` is definitely not a replacement for `new Observable`... but enough in that case :)

Comment: This error happens usually when you operator mistakenly as a "observable creation method". For example you want to use `merge` operators but you import it with `import { merge } from 'rxjs';` which is wrong.

Comment: I have updated my question as it is now throws an other error about incompatible types.

Comment: @maxime1992 right :) that's what I meant, but your comment definitely belongs here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better just use `of()`:

```
of(this.edited.code).pipe(
  debounceTime(defaultInputDebounceTime),
  mergeMap((searchTerm: string) => this.getStrings(searchTerm))
);
```

You are using the `strict: true` flag in your tsconfig.json. This means that it doesn't like you saying that `searchTerm` is a string in the mergeMap, because it can  also be undefined. You can update your `of` to reflect this `of(this.edited.code || '')`, or update your mergeMap typing: `mergeMap((searchTerm: string | undefined)`.